# When running git reset --hard, the staged changes persist. Same goes for git checkout and git stash + git stash drop. What's going on?

Tags: git, mercurial, git-reset

So here's some background:  I'm trying to move a repository [from Mercurial to git](http://hivelogic.com/articles/converting-from-mercurial-to-git) using [hg-fast-export](http://repo.or.cz/w/fast-export.git) and when I do the last step (`git checkout HEAD`) there are still changes that persist in the repository.  Specifically, it says that there are 4 deleted files that shouldn't be deleted.

When I try the following, nothing changes:

`git reset --hard HEAD`, `git checkout .`, `git stash && git stash drop`.

One thing I noticed is odd was that when someone was using this Mercurial repo, they added a git repo right in the middle of it T_T.  So the interesting thing is when I run `git checkout HEAD` (but not when I run `git checkout .`), the `.git` subdirectory appears as deleted in the index (weird).  These changes disappear whenever I run `git reset` but not without a bunch of errors flying past about an Invalid path.

Finally, that leaves the repository in the same state it was in when I first ran `git checkout HEAD`.  (At least git's consistant!).

Surely a subset of the people converting mercurial to git has experienced this.  Can anybody share their experiences with changes persisting within git?

Comment: err, what is the point of `git checkout HEAD` ?  Just after `git reset --hard` what is shown by `git status`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of `git checkout HEAD` is besides updating the working copy of the repository to the HEAD from wherever it was before you ran the script.

After I run `git reset --hard HEAD` I am left with the same 4 files that are listed as deleted in the index that shouldn't be.  They exist on the filesystem but git won't unstage the deletions if I run the above commands.

Comment: As I see it `git checkout HEAD` is a no-op. And you expect it to actually do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this problem was indeed the fact that there was a .git directory inside the mercurial repository.

The way I solved it was running `hg convert` with a filemap excluding the trouble directory before doing the fast export conversion.

Hope this helps someone in the future!